# Give Intellij IDEA Visual Studio's F5, F10 and F11-key functionality

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellij-idea, key-bindings

In Visual Studio, <kbd>F5</kbd> is used both to start debugging and to resume program execution once debugging has started (or "continue").  Intellij has separate commands for debugging (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) and resume program <kbd>F9</kbd>).

Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> (resume program) when the debugger is not running brings up a context menu with a list of launch configurations, while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (start debugging) when the debugger is running appears to start a new instance of the program and kill the old instance (!).  I can map <kbd>F5</kbd> to both resume program and start debugging, but it behaves as if it was mapped to resume program alone.  Instead, I'd like <kbd>F5</kbd> to resume program if the debugger is running, and start debugging otherwise.

Is there any way to change the functionality of a key in Intellij based on whether the debugger is already running, so that I can make the <kbd>F5</kbd> behave like in Visual Studio?

On a related note, is there some way to make <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> (Step Over/Step Into) start debugging at the first line if the debugger is not already running, also like in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (start debugging) when the debugger is running appears to start a new instance of the program and kill the old instance (!)

By default, typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> while a debug session is running will start a new instance in a new tab within the debug tool window. The old instance is still running in a separate tab. If you have the "Single Instance Only" option selected in the Run/Debug configuration, IDEA will prompt you if you wish to stop the current instance. However, if at some point you selected the "Do not show this dialog in the future" option, then it will default to stopping and rerunning.

> Is there any way to change the functionality of a key in Intellij based on whether the debugger is already running, so that I can make the <kbd>F5</kbd> behave like in Visual Studio?

Not directly. However, see next answer...

> On a related note, is there some way to make <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> (Step Over/Step Into) start debugging at the first line if the debugger is not already running, also like in Visual Studio?

If say you map <kbd>F5</kbd> to both "Debug (start)" and "Step Over" (or one of the other step actions) it will start the debugger when not running and perform the step action when not running. I'm not sure why this will not work for doubling up the start debug and resume actions; it most likely has to do with how the editor handles certain actions.

You may want to consider opening a feature request for your desired behavior: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!  Your suggestion of mapping to Debug and Step Over won't work the same way as in Visual Studio, since in Visual Studio pressing F10/F11 starts the debugger on the first line of the program.  In any case, I've made a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110098 thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: I've mapped Menu - Run - Debug to F5, and removed the default mapping of Alt+F5, but it doesn't give the same result as using the mouse to select that menu item. Using the mouse starts debugging on the default debug configuration, but hitting F5 shows a little popup menu and you have to hit Enter to select the default debug configuration. Do you know of any way to map F5 so it avoids this extra keystroke?